# Shorthand Vue bind

Tags: vue.js

In vue there are a couple ways to bind a property to an html tag. For example

```
<span v-bind:style="style"></span>
```

Where `style` exists in the current controller, either as a property or as the component data.

A shorter way to do this is to use the `v-bind` shorthand:

```
<span :style="style"></span>
```

I was wondering if there was a shorter way of doing this, or if there is something similar coming in vue 3, something like this I would like:

```
<span :style></span>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible as of now and not sure about Vue 3 also, as a stable version is not released yet.

Comment: You can do *something like* that with **Vue directives**. I created a snippet as an answer using directives.

Comment: @muka.gergely's comment is missleading as he did NOT correctly understand the question at hand. So folks, don't bother with his answer further down the list.

Comment: @santiago arizti I was looking for the exact same shorthand ... now that makes two of us :D

Comment: Seems like it's intuitive to use. I also thought exact same question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit Jan 2024:

Vue 3.4 implemented precicely the feature I was looking for originally, see [announcement blog post](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-4#v-bind-same-name-shorthand)

> You can now shorten this:
>
> ```
> <img :id="id" :src="src" :alt="alt">
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> <img :id :src :alt>
> ```

---

Edit July 2022:

I tried an even shorter version in the official [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org) and it works. Just use `:="{attr}"` and it works. I have not seen this syntax referenced in the docs so I don't know how official this is. You can even omit the double quotes as it is valid html, but [the style guide frowns upon that](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#quoted-attribute-values).

```
<span :={style}></span>
```

See it in action in the [sfc playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kLFuhDAMhl8lysICZKdw0u3dbs3CgQ84gRM5hqpFvHsNnCpUpJti//nyOfKsr96n0wg603moqPOsAvDoLxYrh0E6/u5BFWquXO8oU1FDABjF6uGQb90PSNSX1ABFy4fF3OwWeZ8zDL4vGaRWKvdqSu4d1tlmLKzeTqsvnw4bCJybdegGnpBb64hVW2J9oHadUPOGLcJdewbCkrsJjrriRewemaVOYG7+fqtj3Q1ewGQoffoMDmU58+qyr4tgdaa2ZM1ke2tvdcvsQ2ZMeFTrSp8hddQYqVIakbsBUghDcif3FYBEbHV8cBgJJ6CEAGsgoHfOf+jJu2oXi4tefgHzy6gk).

Note: playground version ATTOW **@8dcb6c7**

---

Original Answer:

My best solution so far is to use `v-bind`

```
<span v-bind="{style}"></span>
```

It allows you to pass multiple properties at once and then you actually save space, see for example how an img looks like

```
<img v-bind="{alt, src, title}" />
```

Comment: Does it work on Vue 2 too? I saw that sfc.vuejs.org only has Vue 3 playground.

Comment: I tested wit Vue 2.7 with jsfiddle and there was an error ": is not a valid attribute name". I tried both with DOM templates and string templates. I didn't try with a bundler with the vue compiler.

Comment: re: your 2022 edit, i.e. `:="{attr}"`, I get that it works, but how would you actually interpret/decode that? Are there any docs about it?

Answer (score -1):

For that to work you'd need to write your own directive:

```js
Vue.directive('style', {
  bind: function(el) {
    el.classList.add('style')
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.style {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-style>This is styled.</div>
  <div>This is not styled.</div>
  <div v-style>This is styled again.</div>
</div>
```

More on **Vue directives**: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: This doesn't actually implement what the question asks for.

Comment: thanks for the input, perhaps the answer is that there is no way to do this. I was lookinf for a generalized way of passing parameters with same name, kind of how object shorthand works: `const name="myname"; const obj = {name};`